# Average score of reviewers from sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Below is my query giving me result in sum of corresponding value. How can I calculate average here for each column expect Id?

```
Select 
   count(StoreId) as TotalReview, 
   sum(Case OnTimeDelivery when 'Within Time' then 1 else 0 end) as OnTimeDeliveryWithinTime,
   sum(Case OnTimeDelivery when 'Little Delay' then 1 else 0 end) as  OnTimeDeliveryLittleDelay,
   sum(Case OnTimeDelivery when 'Excess Delay' then 1 else 0 end) as OnTimeDeliveryExcessDelay,
from 
   StoreReviews 
where 
   StoreId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT storeId, COUNT(ontimedelivery), AVG(<column>)
FROM storereviews
WHERE storeid=1
GROUP BY ontimedelivery
```

Comment: I tried as per your given solution but returning '0' in AVG. See below query. SELECT storeId, COUNT(storeid), AVG(Case OnTimeDelivery when 'Within Time' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM storereviews
GROUP BY storeid

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake. It's not clear what you are taking the average of

Comment: I want the percentage of people where OnTimeDelivery is 'within time' and so on.

Comment: Please tell me, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the `SUM` for each store based on your own query but you have to add `GROUP BY` like:

```
SELECT Storeid, COUNT(StoreId) as TotalReview, 
SUM(Case OnTimeDelivery WHEN 'Within Time' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OnTimeDeliveryWithinTime,
SUM(Case OnTimeDelivery WHEN 'Little Delay' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as  OnTimeDeliveryLittleDelay,
SUM(Case OnTimeDelivery WHEN 'Excess Delay' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OnTimeDeliveryExcessDelay
FROM StoreReviews 
GROUP BY Storeid
```

Now, if you want to get the **Average** not for each store but for **all stores** and based on `OnTimeDelivery` whether `Within Time` or `Little Delay` or `Excess Delay` you could use `AVG` like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(Decimal(5,2),AVG(CAST(TotalReview as float))) as AvgTotal,  CONVERT(Decimal(5,2),AVG(CAST(OnTimeDeliveryWithinTime as float))) as AvgWithinTime,  CONVERT(Decimal(5,2),AVG(CAST(OnTimeDeliveryLittleDelay as float))) as AvgLittleDelay,  CONVERT(Decimal(5,2),AVG(CAST(OnTimeDeliveryExcessDelay as float))) as AvgExcessDelay
FROM (
SELECT Storeid, COUNT(StoreId) as TotalReview, 
SUM(Case OnTimeDelivery WHEN 'Within Time' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OnTimeDeliveryWithinTime,
SUM(Case OnTimeDelivery WHEN 'Little Delay' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OnTimeDeliveryLittleDelay,
SUM(Case OnTimeDelivery WHEN 'Excess Delay' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OnTimeDeliveryExcessDelay
FROM StoreReviews 
GROUP BY Storeid
) StoreAverages
```

See my [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7259/1)